# Problema com lista encadeada em C

Tags: c, lista, struct, lista-encadeada

**Eu estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade onde basicamente o Programa deve ser feito em linguagem C utilizando listas encadeadas e ter 3 opções:**

1. Adicionar música (início, meio ou fim da lista) com nome, banda e duração;
2. Opção de exibir a lista de músicas;
3. Sair do programa.

Eu criei o código abaixo, porém quando adiciono uma nova música, o ponteiro está apontando para ela mesma, ao invés de apontar para o novo elemento. E quando listo as músicas, acontece que exibe uma lista onde todas as músicas da lista são iguais à última musica adicionada.

**Código:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int menu();
void Listar();
void InserirInicio(char* nome, char* banda, char* duracao);

struct Musica {
    char* nome;
    char* banda;
    char* duracao;
    Musica *prox;
} *Head;

int main() {
    int op;
    char nome[100], banda[100], duracao[10];

    while (1) {
    op = menu();
    switch (op) {
    case 1: //inserir no inicio da lista
        printf("Nome da musica: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(nome, 100, stdin);
        printf("Banda: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(banda, 100, stdin);
        printf("Duracao da musica: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(duracao, 10, stdin);
        InserirInicio(nome, banda, duracao);
        break;
    case 2: //Listar todas as musicas
        Listar();
        break;
    case 3: //sair do programa
        return 0;
    default:
        printf("Invalido\n");
    }
}

return 0;
system("pause");
}

int menu() {
    int opcao, c;
    system("Cls");

    printf("1. Adicionar nova musica\n");
    printf("2. Exibir todas as musicas\n");
    printf("3. Sair\n\n");
    printf("Digite sua escolha: ");

    scanf_s("%d", &opcao);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    system("Cls");
    return opcao;
}

void Listar() {
    Musica *ElementoVarredura;
    ElementoVarredura = (struct Musica *)malloc(sizeof(struct Musica));

    ElementoVarredura = Head;
    if (ElementoVarredura == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int contador = 1;

    while (ElementoVarredura != NULL) {
        printf("%d.\n", contador);
        printf("Nome: %s", ElementoVarredura->nome);
        printf("Artista: %s", ElementoVarredura->banda);
        printf("Duracao: %s", ElementoVarredura->duracao);
        ElementoVarredura = ElementoVarredura->prox;
        contador++;
        printf("\n------------------------------------\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return;
}

void InserirInicio(char* nome, char* banda, char* duracao)
{
    Musica *NovoElemento;
    NovoElemento = (struct Musica *)malloc(sizeof(struct Musica));

    NovoElemento->nome = nome;
    NovoElemento->banda = banda;
    NovoElemento->duracao = duracao;
    NovoElemento->prox = NULL;


    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = NovoElemento;
    }
    else
    {
        NovoElemento->prox = Head;
        Head = NovoElemento;
    }
}
```

O que há de errado?

Comment: Você está lendo várias strings para arrays de char no método principal (alocados na *stack*), depois você passa ponteiros para esses arrays para o método `InserirInicio` e então usa esses ponteiros nas atribuições em `NovoElemento`. Ou seja, todos os ponteiros apontam para endereços de memória dos mesmos arrays (que por sua vez não vivem em memória dinâmica como deveriam). O que você quer na verdade é ou 1) Transformar os `char *` em arrays de caracteres ou 2) Usar uma combinação de `strdup` e `free` para respectivamente copiar as strings para memoria dinâmica e posteriormente liberá-la.

Comment: me ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412245/lista-encadeada-socorro

Answer (score 2):

O problema não é que o ponteiro da sua estrutura está apontando para a própria estrutura, o problema é que os atributos `nome`, `banda` e `duracao` são ponteiros, e o ponteiro de todas as estruturas estão apontando para o mesmo endereço de memória, então quando você altera o valor nesse endereço com `fgets(nome, 100, stdin)` por exemplo, isso reflete em todas as estruturas.

Tente mover a declaração dessas variáveis para a mesma função que você cria a instancia da estrutura, dessa forma você irá criar novas referencias para cada estrutura:

```
void InserirInicio()
{
    char *nome = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char *banda = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char *duracao = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    struct Musica *NovoElemento = (struct Musica *)malloc(sizeof(struct Musica));

    printf("Nome da musica: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(nome, 100, stdin);
    printf("Banda: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(banda, 100, stdin);
    printf("Duracao da musica: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(duracao, 10, stdin);

    NovoElemento->nome = nome;
    NovoElemento->banda = banda;
    NovoElemento->duracao = duracao;
    NovoElemento->prox = NULL;

    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = NovoElemento;
    }
    else
    {
        NovoElemento->prox = Head;
        Head = NovoElemento;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer como falou, mas dá o seguinte erro: Um valor do tipo "void *" não pode ser utilizado para inicializar uma entidade do tipo "char *"

Comment: Você provavelmente está usando um compilador C++. Inclua um cast (`(char*)`) na frente do `malloc`. Alternativamente deixe a leitura com `fgets` como estava antes e faça uma cópia do ponteiro no momento da atribuição aos membros da struct (e.g., `NovoElemento->nome = strdup(nome);`). Em ambos os casos não se esqueça de liberar a memória que alocou usando `free`.

Comment: Perdão, sou iniciante em C e não consegui entender como ficaria isso no código.

Comment: @MikeTaiki, o problema é que `malloc` retorna um dado do tipo `void*`. Em C você pode atribuir esse valor para uma variável de outro tipo, mas C++ exige que você faça o `casting` desse retorno. Adicionei no código esse casting para compilar em C++ também.